# Javascript try/catch fails in handler

Tags: javascript

When I run this:

```
try{
    html5Video.UiEvents.events.resize[1].scope.events.dragend[1].handler(null, {value: 123, pointerEventData: {playing: true}});
}catch(ex){
    console.log("hander failed " + ex.message);
}
```

...in certain scenarios it throws an exception and does not go into the catch block, it just splats all the way to the browser. It doesn't get caught. Right before the `try` I check whether `html5Video.UiEvents.events.resize[1].scope.events.dragend[1]` is null, and I don't continue if it's null. I have verified that it's making it all the way to the handler call before throwing an exception.

The error is:

> subview.trickplay.preview subview.trickplay.preview:
>   uievent|DRAG_MODE_ENTER: TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of
>   null

Why is my catch block not working? What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Most likely you have an error occurring before the `try/catch` block.

Comment: can we see more of your code?

Comment: cartant: I stepped through the code and no error is occurring previous. I also confirmed this with console.log().